# Two Dataframes, one with more columns than the other -> Subtract and Combine

Tags: python, csv, pandas, python-3.5

Ok, I know the title may be a little bit confusing, but I will try to explain this in detail:

I use Python 3.5.2:

I got two .csv files that I read via pandas and convert into two separate dataframes. The first dataframe (coming from XYZ.csv) looks like this:

```
ip              community
10.0.0.1        OL123
.
.
.
123.12.5.31    IK753
```

The second (export.csv) just has the "ip" column.

Now what I want to do:

I want to compare the two dataframes and as a result get a third dataframe (or list) that contains all ip-addresses that are in the first dataframe but not in the other WITH their correlating community. So far, I managed to compare the two and get a proper result, as long as the second dataframe also contains the communities. I manually inserted those communites into the second export.csv, unfortunately I cannot automate this and that is why I need this to work without the second dataframe containing the communities.

This is my code:

```
def compare_csvs():
         timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    # Reads XYZ.csv and creates list that contains all ip addresses in integer format.
         A = pd.read_csv("XYZ.csv", index_col=False, header=0)
         ips1 = A.ip.tolist()
         comu1 = A.ro_community.tolist()
         AIP = []
         for element1 in ips1:
                  AIP.append(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(element1)))
         IPACOM1 = zip(AIP,comu1)              

    # Reads export.csv and creates list that contains all ip addresses in integer format.
         B = pd.read_csv("export" + timestamp + ".csv", index_col=False, header=0)
         ips2 = B.ip.tolist()
         comu2 = B.ro_community.tolist()
         BIP = []
         for element2 in ips2:
                  BIP.append(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(element2)))
         IPACOM2 = zip(BIP,comu2)

    # Creates a set that contains all ip addresses (in integer format) that exist inside the XYZ.csv but not the export.csv.
         DeltaInt = OrderedSet(IPACOM1)-OrderedSet(IPACOM2)
         List = list(DeltaInt)
         UnzippedIP = []
         UnzippedCommunity = []
         UnzippedIP, UnzippedCommunity = zip(*List)

    # Puts all the elements of the DeltaInt set inside a list and also changes the integers back to readable IPv4-addresses.
         DeltaIP = []
         for element3 in UnzippedIP:
              DeltaIP.append(str(ipaddress.IPv4Address(element3)))

         IPandCommunity = zip(DeltaIP,UnzippedCommunity)
```

Now all I need is something that can compare the two lists I created and keep the "community" with the "ip" it is assigned to. I tried a whole lot but I can't seem to get anything to work. Maybe I am just having a problem with the logic here, all help is appreciated!

Also, excuse the code mess, I just threw all that together and will clean it up once the code actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some dummy data to play with:

This is df:

```
ip              community
10.0.0.1        OL123
10.1.1.1        ACLSH
10.9.8.7        OKUAJ1
123.12.5.31     IK753

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

This is export.csv:

```
s_export = pd.Series(s_export = pd.Series(name='ip', data=['10.1.1.1','123.12.5.31', '0.0.0.0'])

s_export

0       10.1.1.1
1    123.12.5.31
2        0.0.0.0
Name: ip, dtype: object
```

To select the ones that aren't in export, we can simply use boolean indexing using [isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
# ~ means 'not', so here that's "find df.ip that is NOT in s_export"
# Store result in a dataframe
df_exclude = df[~df.ip.isin(s_export)]


df_exclude
         ip community
0  10.0.0.1     OL123
2  10.9.8.7    OKUAJ1
```

Comment: The concept of isin() seems helpful, unfortunately though, I don't get the right results. The result simply contains the whole dataframe "df" and doesn't exclude the ones inside the export.csv.

Comment: Did you try running the specific example I gave you? I'm 100% sure it works

Comment: Ah, I found the issue. It works as soon as I convert the "B" dataframe into a series with the parameter "squeeze=True". As output, I now got a dataframe that contains the relevant ip-addresses aswell as their communities. That is a big step in the right direction, thank you!